# IDA LoadLibraryError

Tags: ida

I installed IDA Demo today, however I'm having a bit of trouble installing plugins. I'm trying to install a plugin called 'ClassInformer'. I followed all the instructions, editing the plugins.cfg file, copying the files to the plugin folder. However when I boot up IDA it gives me these errors:

```
LoadLibrary(C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA Demo 6.9\plugins\IDA_ClassInformer_PlugIn.pLW) error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA Demo 6.9\plugins\IDA_ClassInformer_PlugIn.pLW: can't load file

LoadLibrary(C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA Demo 6.9\plugins\IDA_ClassInformer_PlugIn.pLW) error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA Demo 6.9\plugins\IDA_ClassInformer_PlugIn.pLW: can't load file
```

However the files are in the correct folder so I don't know why they can't be found. Here's a picture of the children of the folder.

[Folder Children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnaYi.png)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that the Demo does not allow plugins.

Comment: @tmr232 I am not sure. However when the analysis is done, if I try to run the plugin it works fine. So I'm not sure why its erroring out, but it seems to not have any trouble running.

Comment: This could also be related to compilation and binary incompatability instead